# How to Rewrite my url from index.php to sample.php

Tags: url, seo, url-rewriting

i want to Rewrite my url from index.php to sample.php. how can i do this? iam not allowed to rename index.php to sample.php and make it landing url.is it using .htaccess?

Comment: IAM USING JOOMLA , XAMPP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this line in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ sample.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: its working, but everyone recommends not to rewrite from index.php to other name. anyway thanks for your contribution..

Answer (score 0):

if you're on linux you could just create a sym-link.

```
ln -s index.php sample.php
```

on windows it would be:

```
mklink /D sample.php index.php
```

Comment: But then you would need to add `Options +FollowSymLinks` to your .htaccess file, if your host isn't already configured that way.

Comment: oh, didn't know that.. for me it worked all the time

Comment: iam using windows xaamp

Comment: hi, iam a begginer on htaccess

Comment: it redirect to sample.php page

Comment: and shows page not found, so do we need to rename our index.php file to sample.php?